# Google Maps - Click Marker Open InfoWindow and Draw Route

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to both open and infowindow and draw the route between a 'home' marker and the marker clicked?
What I've got is multiple markers on a map with a 'home' marker.  I'd like to have the route drawn on the map from this 'home' marker to the marker clicked.

Comment: Sure it is possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an event listener on your markers for the `click` event.  Within that, use the `DirectionsService` to draw your route.

Comment: Right.  That simple.  Thanks.